# Three connected pieces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $f$ be a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ such that $f$ on $(0,1)$ has connected graph and $f$ has dense graph on  $(0,1)$  and $$f \restriction (\Bbb R\setminus (0,1))=0$$ $Gr(f)$ denotes to the graph of $f.$ $Gr(f)$ is the union of three piece that are connected. It seems to me the the whole graph will be connected but I want to argue for that. Many thanks

Comment: What if $f \restriction (0,1)=1$?

Comment: @SteveKass, I fixed it . $f$  is not constant on $(0,1)$

Comment: even if it's not constant you may have $f$ on $(0,1)$ is $x+1$ which will give you 3 connected components

Comment: @aldodecristo, I fixed . I made it dense graph on $(0,1)$

Comment: if the graph is dense then it cannot be continuous (the graph of a continuous function is a closed set in the product topology given some nice topological properties). So it wouldn't be 3 connected parts.

Comment: @aldodecristo, So, it seems only connected graph on $(0,1)$ would  not be enough What kind of conditions may add with connected on $(0,1)$  to make sure the whole graph will be connected

Comment: that it's continuous in $(0,1)$ and the limits at $0$ and $1$ are both zero

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120795/discussion-between-00gb-and-aldo-decristo).

Comment: @aldodecristo, could you please explain why this would be enough to make the whole graph connected